# I want to send the user an email acknowledging him and updating his status to complete in my MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is my PHP script to inform a user whose status I've just changed that he can get his card printed from my website, this doesn't seem to mail my customer, it just updates the table. MySQL connection string has been purpotedly hidden.

```
<?php
  session_start();

  $con=mysqli_connect(*);

  // Check connection

  if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


  if(isset($_POST['Request']))
  {
    $result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT req_date,Name,Mobile,Email FROM pend WHERE Mobile LIKE '" . mysql_escape_string($_POST['Mobile']) . "'; ");
    $row =mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_BOTH);
    $Mmobile = $row['Mobile'];
    $email=$row['Email'];
    $name=$row['Name'];
    $req=$row['req_date'];

    if($Mobile == $Mmobile) {
      $message = '<html><body>';
      $message .= '<img src="http://www.mbdr.ml/admin/logo.jpg" alt="Blood Recieved" />';
      $message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
      $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Name:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['Name']) . "</td></tr>";
      $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Mobile:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['Mobile']) . "</td></tr>";
      $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Blood Group:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['Bld_grp']) . "</td></tr>";
      $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Date Requested:</strong> </td><td>" . $_POST['req_Date'] . "</td></tr>";
      $message .= "</table>";
      $message .= "<a href='http://www.mbdr.ml/lel/lol.php'> Get Your Card After Logging in From Here </a>";
      $message .= "</body></html>";
      //   CHANGE THE BELOW VARIABLES TO YOUR NEEDS
      $to = strip_tags($_POST['Email']);
      $subject = 'Blood Donor Card';
      $headers = "From: " . $cleanedFrom . "\r\n";
      $headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['Email']) . "\r\n";
      $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
      $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

      if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
        echo 'Your message has been sent.';
      } 
      else {
        echo 'There was a problem sending the email.';
      }
    } 
    else {
      echo "You didn't enter the correct details!";
    }
    $query=mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE pend SET status='complete' WHERE Mobile LIKE '" . mysql_escape_string($_POST['Mobile']) . "'; ");

    if (!$query) {
      printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
      exit();
    }
    $row =mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_BOTH);
    $Mmobile = $row['Mobile'];

    if($Mobile == $Mmobile) {
      header("Location:http://www.mbdr.ml/admin/adminpage.php");
    } else {
      echo "You didn't enter the correct details!";
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
  }

>
```

Comment: A separate issue but `mysql_escape_string` doesn't work with `mysqli`. Where do you define `$Mobile`? You also execute the update outside the conditional..

Comment: @chris85 will try to circumvent that and try

Comment: The update query is executing, but are you seeing "There was a problem sending the email" or "You didn't enter the correct details!".

Comment: @LoganBailey even the echo isn't printing an output

Comment: @chris85 ii require the code to first send the mail and then update the table

Comment: Yea, but if you run into the `You didn't enter the correct details!` you shouldn't be updating, correct? Where does this code fail currently; is it just a white page?

Answer (score 0):

Re-write the line

```
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT req_date,Name,Mobile,Email FROM pend WHERE Mobile LIKE '" . mysql_escape_string($_POST['Mobile']) . "'; ");
```

as

```
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT req_date,Name,Mobile,Email FROM pend WHERE Mobile LIKE '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Mobile']) . "'; ");
```

and change every `mysql_escape_string` to `mysqli_real_escape_string`

note: `mysqli_real_escape_string` expects 2 parameters